# Is a Kuo-Toa god on the same power level as those found in other pantheons?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, religions-and-deities

The [kuo-toa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-k#Kuotoa), according to the *Monster Manual* (p. 198), have a unique power detailed in the section *God Makers*:

> Kuo-toa worship gods of their own insane creation, but if enough kuo-toa believe that a god is real, the energy of their collective subconscious can cause that god to manifest as a physical entity.

Also, [kuo-toa archpriests](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kuo-toa-archpriest) (p. 200) are 10th-level clerics...

> The kuo-toa is a 10th-level spellcaster. Its spellcasting ability is Wisdom. [...] The kuo-toa has the following cleric spells prepared:

...with notes about the source of this magic (p. 198):

> An archpriest’s mad belief in its god is so fervent that it manifests the powers of a high cleric.

Factoring in these details, are the gods that the kuo-toa domains manifest comparable in power to the other gods from the pantheons listed in the *Player's Handbook*?

Answer (score 21):

## At least one of them, if you consider older edition info

This is partially drawn from some older information, but here you go...

As you stated, the Monster Manual says that Kuo-Toa 'create' gods by believing in them so hard that they manifest. It continues to say this...

> One of the most revered gods of the kuo-toa is Blibdoolpoolp the Sea Mother, who takes the form of a female human with a crayfish head, a crayfish’s claws, and an articulated shell covering her shoulders. Blibdoolpoolp was likely invented by a kuo-toa that improved on a broken human statue by adding the limbs and head of a crustacean. In sudden awe of its handiwork, it then named the resulting form a god.

While no 5E information exists expanding on this, there is some 3E material that covers this particular goddess.

From the 3rd Edition book Faiths and Pantheons, we have a table on page 221 (list of non-human deities) that has record of Blibdoolpoolp. She is listed as an Intermediate Deity, thus being on the same power level as gods such as Kelemvor, Tymora, Lloth (Lolth), and Helm. She has the Domains of Destruction, Evil, and Water (Pared back to just 'Death' in 5E, see [Appendix B](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/appendix-b-gods-of-the-multiverse) of the DMG.)

The 3rd Edition book *Player's Guide to Faerun* gives us a little more details. On page 53, it introduces her Home Plane: The Fated Depths, which she shared with Sekolah, the god of the Sahuagin.

> The Drowning Goddess, on the other hand, does have a realm—a spherical temple that resembles a small moon drifting through the unholy waters of the plane.

So, as we can see from here...Blibdoolpoolp is spoken of in the same breath and in the same manner as all other gods. Apart from the fact that she was created by her worshipers believing in her hard enough, she appears to be a fully functional deity.

Now, as for any other gods they may invent...the books are less clear. The phrasing makes it clear that a newly invented god has to reach a critical mass of worshipers before it would be possible for them to actually exist, but specific details are never provided.

Of note, The Fated Depths apparently ceased to exist during the Spellplague. We have no updated information from 4E or 5E on where Blibdoolpoolp presently resides.

Comment: I think you should lead with the fact that she shows up in the Nonhuman Deities list. I had missed that

Answer (score -5):

Yes, if they have enough worshipers. I assume they are like Vestiges and need worshipers to reach the status lesser and eventually become a greater god or goddess.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).